# Dancer and generating forms

Tags: forms, perl, validation, dancer

I have an issue where forms are validated and if do not pass validation (validation is done in the back-end) are re displayed with original submitted data for the user to change. Originally this was not huge as I could just pass param data back into the template and have it re-displayed to the user. However, I came across issues with getting drop-downs and check boxes to retain the submitters original choices.

I checked out some of the Dancer friendly modules that did form validation and they seem nice, however, I have one more constraint: The forms and data selected needs to be able to be rebuilt and displayed again at a later time. So that means the data will need to be retrieved and the form built again displaying the same information previously selected, dropdowns already preselected, checkboxes checked, and data with the inputs.

I do not mind generating the forms and their selections dynamically from the backend using CGI form generating methods, but how can I get that data to play nice with dancer and display inside of a template?

Comment: Can you post the template for your form (particularly drop-downs and checkboxes)? And can you clarify "The forms and data selected needs to be able to be rebuilt and displayed again at a later time". Does this mean you need to persist the invalid form and re-display when the user returns?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to redisplay at a later time, it seems to me that you could go with a poor man's solution--save the rendered form with stuff selected to disk or database, and when it needs to be displayed again, just thow that cached stuff at them--or write the params to storage, and when you need to redisplay, go through the same code that generates the form now but use the saved params.

The "poor man's method" would be easy to implement but would bite you later when you find you are showing people stale versions of the form or whatever.  (This is also a possible issue with the other version--the set of parameters might change over time, so there's risk there, too, but I would think less risk as you are caching less.)

I'm sorry that this is a "how to solve your problem" answer rather than a "here's a module that solves your problem answer".  However, it's not too hard to store a set of params as a json blob or some other sort of frozen object, and there are modules for all the pieces of this.